# React Native unable to run ios on a brand new project

Tags: react-native

I am new to `React-Native` and start following the new architecture documentation (https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/use-app-template)

I followed all the steps and was able to run the Android version, but I cannot run the iOS version.  I get the following error when I run `yarn ios`:

> The following build commands failed:
> PhaseScriptExecution Bundle\ React\ Native\ code\ and\ images /Users//Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/-erircyesievlkpbyjwzgmkczjzah/Build/Intermediates.noindex/.build/Debug-iphoneos/.build/Script-00DD1BFF1BD5951E006B06BC.sh (in target '' from project '')
> (1 failure)
>
> where 'app' is the name of my app.

My machine is a Mac and runs on Ventura 13.5, Xcode 15.0.1 and Node 21. Here is my package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "<app>",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "npx react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "pod-install": "RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.73.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/babel-preset": "^0.73.18",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.73.2",
    "@react-native/typescript-config": "^0.73.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.6.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.6.3",
    "prettier": "2.8.8",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18"
  }
}
```

I tried cleaning the build folder (as suggested in the documentation), but that did not help.

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Try to use ```npx create-react-native-app``` to create a new project.

Comment: @MichaelBahl This creates an expo app.  My understanding is that I cannot use Expo with the new architecture.  See the Caution note here:  https://reactnative.dev/docs/the-new-architecture/use-app-template#development-environment

Comment: AFAIK new arch should be available now -> https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/23410

Comment: I do not want to use Expo at the moment.  I prefer the flexibility of working directly with the CLI.

Comment: You can use expo with cli.

Comment: First, have you tried it without new arch? Does it work without?